# memory Stuck in Solaris can't free memory

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, opensolaris, sun, solaris-11

I am Working On Solaris 11, Now facing problem related to memory 
As my root is reached to 90%, I have deleted the audit file from /var/share/audit which is of 8 GB after deleting the file,server doesn't free that memory . Why ? How can free that memory without reboot the server ?

Comment: Do you mean memory (RAM) or disk space (you said root and you deleted some files)?

Comment: file system Memory(Disk space)

Comment: Was the file still open?  If so, [that's expected behavior as space for open files in Unix-type systems (Solaris, Linux, BSD...) isn't freed when the file is deleted - it remains on disk until the file is closed.](https://www.google.com/search?q=deleted+file+space+not+freed)

Comment: Check all the system processes. Removed file doesn't used by any process ... is their any other way to find the file is open or not ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle is it because of cache memory ?

Comment: Their is no zombie process and Nathing in cache and /var/temp folder

Comment: I think this is what you're saying:  *Your storage is full on root.  You deleted an 8GB audit file from /var/share/audit, and root free space did not increase.*  You need to learn to communicate the difference between memory and storage.  /var could easily be on a separate partition from root.  Check your mounts to see if there is a partition mounted at /var.  In RHEL you could use `cat /etc/fstab`, or `mount`, or `df -h` to see the mounting table, current mounts, or mounted partitions.